# Vary cmake cppFlags in native module gradle based on app module build

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have an android studio project that contains the following modules:

1. Library module for Java/Kotlin stuff
2. Native library module for JNI/cpp stuff
3. App module A
4. App module B

I have 2 apps with different activities and layouts that are sharing a lot of backend stuff. I want to be able to do preprocessor if statements based on the app module that I am building for like this:

```
#ifdef APP_A
// do this
#else
// do that
#endif
```

But I'm not sure how I can pass in different compile flags to the gradle build script:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        cppFlags "-std=c++17"
        arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared", "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug"
    }
}
```